# Does updating to 17.10 from 17.04 removes all my softwares?

Tags: upgrade

I am currently using 17.04 ubuntu now. Update manager is asking me to update to a new 17.10 version of ubuntu. And I really want to update.

My question is on updating will I loose all my softwares in the current version?

Answer (score 0):

It would only touch/upgrade packages and dependencies which are part of official 17.10 repositories. Other software should not be removed. However, there may be compatibility issues due to some changes in the latest version, so I suggest you check the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes).